# Anchoring layout to bottom sheet

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I am attempting to anchor a view to the top and horizontal center of a bottom sheet but am running into issues. When I set the anchor gravity of the view being attached to the bottom sheet to `center_horizontal`, the view will be slightly off center.

Current XML code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/pull_tab"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_sheet"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        >
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
        app:behavior_draggable="true"
        app:behavior_hideable="true"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="55dp">
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Xm5Y.png)

**Edit:** What I am trying to accomplish here is to have the anchored view always visible on the horizontal center of the bottom sheet even when the bottom sheet is hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below code

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**bottom_sheet.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="false"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <View
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp" 
            android:background="@color/black" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@color/grey1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do not think I have explained my issue very well. I want to have the view that I am anchoring to the bottom sheet be always visible even when the bottom sheet is completely hidden. That way I can have the bottom sheet opened again when the view is pressed.

Comment: Remove this line `app:behavior_peekHeight="55dp"` from your xml or set it to 0dp